# Definitions of isomorphism and elementary substructures

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

Let us define -all the definitions are from V. Manca, *Logica matematica*, 2001, 'mathematical logic'- a $\Sigma$-*morphism* as a function $f:D_1\to D_2$ between models $\mathscr{M}_1$ and $\mathscr{M}_2$, having respective universes $D_1$ and $D_2$, which preserves all **the atomic formulas** of model $\mathscr{M}_1$. Here I am not sure of a thing: atomic formulas can contain free variables, but can $f$ preserve a formula where free variables appears? If it can, I am not sure I understand what preservation is.

The definition of a $\Sigma$-***isomorphism*** that I have in my book is that of a **bijective $\Sigma$-morphism**.

Let us define an *elementary* $\Sigma$-*embedding* as an injective $\Sigma$-morphism between models $\mathscr{M}_1$ and $\mathscr{M}_2$ preserving all the formulas of model $\mathscr{M}_1$.

Let us define an *elementary $\Sigma$-substructure* $\mathscr{M}$ of $\mathscr{M}'$ as a $\Sigma$-model $\mathscr{M}$ whose universe $D$ is a subset of the universe $D'$ of $\mathscr{M}'$ and whose inclusion function $\iota: D\hookrightarrow D'$ is an elementary $\Sigma$-embedding.

I read, in the same book, that $\mathscr{M}$ is elementarily $\Sigma$-embedded into $\mathscr{M}'$ if and only if $\mathscr{M}$ is $\Sigma$-isomorphic to an elementary $\Sigma$-substructure of $\mathscr{M}'$.

I have [found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080612/elementary-embeddings-vs-isomorphisms/1081186#1081186) **alternative definitions of isomorphism** where it is implied that an *isomorphism* preserves **all** the formulas of the model. Is this definition equivalent to requiring that it preserves the atomic formulas?

if it is not, I understand that $\mathscr{M}$ is elementarily $\Sigma$-embedded into $\mathscr{M}'$ only if $\mathscr{M}$ is $\Sigma$-isomorphic to an elementary $\Sigma$-substructure of $\mathscr{M}'$, but I do not understand why $\mathscr{M}$ is elementarily $\Sigma$-embedded into $\mathscr{M}'$ if $\mathscr{M}$ is $\Sigma$-isomorphic to an elementary $\Sigma$-substructure of $\mathscr{M}'$; how could it be proved? I thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: About the meaning of "preservation". The truth of a formula $\phi(x)$ is preserved by $f:D_1\to D_2$ if $M_1\models\phi(a)\Rightarrow M_2\models\phi(fa)$ for every tuple $a\in D^{|x||}$.

Comment: An equivalent way of defining elementary embedding is as follows. We say that $f:D_1\to D_2$ is an elementary embedding if it is total and preserves the truth of all formulas. When $D_1\subseteq D_2$ and $f$ is the identity map, we say that $M_1\preceq M_2$. (You may find this formulation more clear. It is equivalent to what you write.)